# Settimeout() not working synchronusly

Tags: jquery, settimeout, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page with a submitbutton.When submit button is clicked,I need to show a dialog box with some notification messages for 2 seconds.After 2 seconds,I need to redirect the page to another location.

```
setTimeout(function(){
       $('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close');                
                                }, 2000);
//after this popup closes,I need to redirect to another page
 window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
```

When I do this,dialog comes and immediately page is asynchronously leading to next page.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close');}, 2000).then(function(){
    window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
    });
```

This is not working.

Comment: Do you `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` on your form submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't return a promise, it returns a number; so there's no `then` function available on it.

Just put the `location` assignment after the call to close the dialog, *within* the `setTimeout` callback:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close');                
    window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
}, 2000);
```

Or if you have an animation on the dialog close, put the `location` assignment in the [`close` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) of the dialog:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close').on("dialogclose", function() {
        window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
    });                
}, 2000);
```

That will wait to change the location until the animation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

if you are redirecting to another page there is no need to close the dialog, but i guess it makes sense if it takes timt to get response from the server. Anyway:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close');
    window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a close event handler to the dialog:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#wrapper_dialog').dialog('close');
    $( "#wrapper_dialog" ).on( "dialogclose", function() {
        window.location = "?load=parents/communication";
    });
}, 2000);
```

See the [dialog widget documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)